# How to get a input from user to use as url path directory in php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dom

i am working on a upload page for customers to upload some files into wordpress site. The point of doing that is get some numbers from users as variable and create the folder by using that variable. Here is my code, it actually creates a folder and puts the image inside the folder successfuly. What i want is if user inputs "5389" as number, than folder should be uploaded in "/wp-content/useruploads/5389/image.png"

here is my code

```
<?php /* Template Name: Create Custom Upload Path */ ?>
<?php 

global $wp_filesystem;
WP_Filesystem();

$content_directory = $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir() ;
$wp_filesystem->mkdir( $content_directory . 'useruploads' );

$target_dir_location = $content_directory . 'useruploads/';
 
if(isset($_POST["submittheform"]) && isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
 
    $name_file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
 
    if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $target_dir_location.$name_file ) ) {
        echo "File was successfully uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "The file was not uploaded";
    }
 
}

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submittheform">
</form>
```

i tried to have one more post method and get build number, then use it as variable but was not able to make it happen. any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I’d recommend turning on WordPress and PHP error reporting to see if anything jumps out at you

Comment: @ChrisHaas actually this code is working but could not figure out how to create a subdirectory under useruploads folder with the input user types. just like /wp-content/useruploads/"numberhere"/filename.png

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t tell where the actual problem was. I’m not seeing a field in the form for someone to put that number?